# Django serialize one field only instead of whole model in related fields (readonly)

Tags: python, django, serialization, model, django-rest-framework

I'd like to serialize a nested model field that only has one field by using the field of the nested model directly.

Following code should explain the situation:

```py
# models
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Scene(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

# serializers
class SceneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'tags',)
        read_only_fields = ('tags',)
```

which outputs the following if used:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "yolol",
    "tags": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

What I'd like to have is the following output (using Tag.title instead of the primary key):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "A Scene",
    "tags": [
        "3D",
        "Industry"
    ]
}
```

How do I write a serializer that does this for the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`SlugRelatedField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class SceneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='title'
     )
    class Meta:
        model = Scene
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'tags',)
```